# WebResponse Content-Length Returns -1

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, content-length, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have tried this code with other links and its works. But on this [link](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4) content-length returns -1.

Methot 1 :

```
System.Net.WebRequest wr = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_link);
wr.Method = "HEAD";
using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = wr.GetResponse())
{
   string ContentLength = resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
}
```

Methot 2 :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_link);
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    long ContentLength = response.ContentLength;
}
```

How can i get the Content-Length?

Answer (score 0):

If you get -1, there is no `Content-Length` header in the response.

That make sense with the HEAD verb, which does not send any content, just the headers.

If you change the verb by GET, the content length will return the reponse length.